# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql

I have just installed `xampp` on `Mac`.

I was trying to import an existing `.sql` file to `MySQL DB` on `phpMyAdmin`.

It was a success.

But I cannot connect `MySQL` using `mysql browser like Sequel Pro`.

I think this is because of `ERROR (2002)`

This is the result when I type `mysql` on the terminal.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

Please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked it out [here](https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/08/solved-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket.html).
It means either the MySQL server is not installed/running, or the file mysql.sock doesn’t exist in /var/lib/mysql/.

There are a couple of solutions for this error.

1. First, check to see whether mysqld service is running or not. If not, start it:

```
service mysqld start
Then try to connect again.
```

2. Try to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

If you connect to localhost, it will use the socket connector, but if you connect to 127.0.0.1 the TCP/IP connector will be used. So when the socket connector is not working, try connecting to 127.0.0.1 instead.

3. Edit file my.cnf

Find the file my.cnf (usually in /etc/) to edit and add these following line:

```
[mysqld]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

[client]

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Restart mysql and connect again.
```

4. Symlink

In some cases, you mysql.sock might be located in another folder. You have to find and symlink it. You might find it in /tmp/mysql.sock or /data/mysql_datadir/mysql.sock

For example, your file is located as in /tmp/mysql.sock

Then symlink it:

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
Restart mysql and connect again.
```

Comment: for me I had to change `localhost` to '127.0.0.1'